# I get error message "Invalid ESP-IDF" when I configure the ESP-IDF extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32

Step 1: Install VS Code
Step 2: Get ESP-IDF Explorer Extension
Step 3: Click View -> Command Palette
Step 4: Write "ESP-IDF: Configure ESP-IDF extension" and click
Step 5: Click "EXPRESS"

I then get the error message: Invalid ESP-IDF

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.